# Why doesn't this simple if statement work?

Tags: php

I have a simple thing I'm trying to solve.

I have a date stored in a table, and I'm comparing it to a php generated date.

ie:

```
if($row['start_date'] < date("Y-m-d")) {

    // table stored date larger than php date
    echo 'hi';

}  else {

    // php date larger than table stored date
    echo 'bye';

}
```

This seems ok to me, but

```
if $row['start_date'] === '2011-09-13' AND date("Y-m-d") === '2011-09-15'.
```

I end up with:

```
hi
```

This could be one of those twilight moments where I think left is right and a *greater than* symbol is actually a *less than*. So please help me - why doesn't this work?

Comment: I suggest [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: Hmmm, but isn't `'2011-09-13' < '2011-09-15'` true?

Comment: in PHP are string comparable lexigraphically using `<`? Probably best to convert to some numeric type (unix timestamp?) and compare that instead.

Comment: @Evan Teran: they are. And the code should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$row['start_date'] = '2011-09-13'` and `date("Y-m-d") = '2011-09-15'`, then your PHP date is greater than the row's date and thus the `if`  is true, after all `'2011-09-13'` is "smaller (`<`)" than `'2011-09-15'`. Flip your `<` to `>` and you'll be fine.

```
if($row['start_date'] > date("Y-m-d")) {

    // table stored date larger than php date
    echo 'hi';

}  else {

    // php date larger than table stored date
    echo 'bye';

}
```

Answer (score 4):

To compare dates you have to use `strtotime()` for `$row['start_date']` and `time()`

```
if(strtotime($row['start_date']) < time())
```

Comment: You don't "have to" use `strtotime()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtotime()` to convert the string to unix timestamp then compare.
Or use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the validity of comparing dates as strings, using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) or [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) and comparing timestamps may be more robust options but with this date format it should work as strings.

Other than that, your logic seems to work as written (if not as intended). "...13" **is** less than "...15", so the `if` will evaluate to `true` and "hi" will be printed.

Judging by the inline comments, it seems it may in fact be one of those twilight moments you speak of.